# HTTParty is escaping JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to send data to a remote API, however the API is complaining because the JSON being sent by HTTParty appears to be being escaped, and is thus deemed invalid.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
query = {"count"=>1,
 "workspaces"=>
  {123445=>
    {"title"=>"Test Project",
     "description"=>"",
     "start_date"=>"2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "due_date"=>"2015-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "price_in_cents"=>8000,
     "currency"=>"USD",
     "status_key"=>130,
     "custom_field_values_attributes"=>[],
     "workspace_groups_attributes"=>
      [{"created_at"=>"2015-07-13T11:06:36-07:00",
        "updated_at"=>"2015-07-13T11:06:36-07:00",
        "name"=>"Test Customer",
        "company"=>true,
        "contact_name"=>nil,
        "email"=>nil,
        "phone_number"=>nil,
        "address"=>nil,
        "website"=>nil,
        "notes"=>nil,
        "id"=>"530947",
        "custom_field_values_attributes"=>[]}],
     "id"=>123445}},
 "results"=>[{"key"=>"workspaces", "id"=>123445}]}
```

Calling `to_json` on `query` escapes the JSON too:

```
"{\"count\":1,\"workspaces\":{\"123445\":{\"title\":\"Test Project\",\"description\":\"\",\"start_date\":\"2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"due_date\":\"2015-08-31T00:00:00.000Z\",\"price_in_cents\":8000,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"status_key\":130,\"custom_field_values_attributes\":[],\"workspace_groups_attributes\":[{\"created_at\":\"2015-07-13T11:06:36-07:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-07-13T11:06:36-07:00\",\"name\":\"Test Customer\",\"company\":true,\"contact_name\":null,\"email\":null,\"phone_number\":null,\"address\":null,\"website\":null,\"notes\":null,\"id\":\"530947\",\"custom_field_values_attributes\":[]}],\"id\":123445}},\"results\":[{\"key\":\"workspaces\",\"id\":123445}]}"
```

Is this expected behavior to escape the JSON? Or I'm wondering if the hash I'm building for `query` is invalid for JSON purposes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks fine, do you control the remote server?

Comment: Hey @Adam! Do you have any further questions regarding this issue? :)

Answer (score 3):

Calling to_json on query doesn't yield escaped JSON.

Try `puts query.to_json` to see that.

You see backslashes because `#inspect` method on String (and this method is called to display contents of variables to console) displays String enclosed in double quotes, and it has to escape quotes which are in the given string itself.

Your problem is probably not having proper Content-Type headers. You should do something like this:

```
result = HTTParty.post(url, body: query.to_json, headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```